# Distraction-free Linux distro

Tags: linux, ubuntu, google-chrome

I think this is an OK place to ask this, but if not, please tell me where I should post it.

I'm a student who is easily distracted by any notifications that come on my computer. So, I want to install a distro that I use just for school stuff, and have it be as distraction-free as possible.

Requirements:

- Must support Google Chrome
- Have minimal to no notifications for software updating or anything
- KDE or Gnome
- No unnecessary applications installed (games, media software, etc.)
- Have LibreOffice or OpenOffice

Or, if anyone knows how to disable all notifications and all that jazz on Ubuntu, that works too.

Comment: Google for each specific annoyance, "disable updates ubuntu", "disable notifications ubuntu", etc. It's not that hard to do. Uninstalling software is super easy too, use `apt-get remove` or uninstall from the software centre.

Comment: I understand that, I was just wondering if there was a distro that already came like that. It seems like something that would be pretty useful for students like me.

Comment: Software recommendations don't belong here. If you want a good place for them, check this out: [softwarerecs.se]

Comment: Disabling updates is **not** a good idea.

Comment: Building your own may be an option, though forget KDE or gnome - Something based off TWM or openbox would be lighter, and you could just install what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be exactly what you want, but it's all that's popping into my head.

1. Download and install Ubuntu Server. Think of it as Ubuntu Desktop without a desktop environment installed yet, or any of the pre-installed gui applications.
2. Login, and run:

   > sudo apt-get update
3. Install the following:

   > sudo apt-get install kde-plasma-dektop && sudo apt-get install libreoffice
4. Remove the following (this program is for installing system updates!!!)

   > sudo apt-get remove update-manager
5. Install Google Chrome.

Notes:

- The reason I suggest removing update manager rather than just opening and unchecking the appropriate settings boxes is that in my experience recent versions have a bug where update manager ignores your changes and continues to make your life hell.
- It's been a while a while since I used KDE on server so I can't recall what exactly is installed. In fact update manager may not even be? Saves you a step I guess.
- You will still get some system tray notifications, but you can just remove the widget from your panel by right clicking and editing the panel.